# Add zero in single date in front in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Whenever I run this code with setInterval (fun(),1000) then seconds are shown until 09, and it doesn't show seconds from 10 to 59.

```
if (secs < 10) 
{
secs = "0" + sec;
document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = ":" + " " + secs;
}
```

Comment: You've to set `.innerHTML` outside of the `if` statement block.

Comment: What is your question again?

Comment: Is this the entirety of fun()?

Can you please rephrase your question to be more specific and please include enough code for it to be repeatable? Add zero in single date in front of javascript? What do you actually mean, are you talking about padding left?

Answer (score 0):

`sec.padStart(2, '0');` Where 2 are the minimum digits and '0' the char you want to add.